# Find the real vector space of the solutions of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Let $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ for $i = 1,2$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 0,1$ with,
\begin{equation}
  (z - a_1)(z - a_2) = z^2 + b_1z + b_0, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

I would like to find the real vector space of the solutions of the following ODE,
\begin{equation}
  y''(x) + b_1 y'(x) + b_0 y(x) = 0
\end{equation}

However I have no idea how to do that.
Should I first compute the characteristic polynomial then find the set of general solutions and then do something to find the vector space ?

Comment: The set of general solutions will be of the form $C_1y_1+C_2y_2$ where $y_1,y_2$ are two linearly independent solutions of the ODE. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $y=e^{mx}$ is solution of given ODEs. Using this function, we can have
$$
m^{2}+b_{1}m+b_{0}=0. 
$$
This will have two solutions, say $y_1 , y_2$. Therefore, you may construct a basis with these solutions and then Vector space is generated by the same basis. If this equation has no real roots like the following form
$$m^{2}+1=0.$$
Then solution is of the form $e^{ix}, e^{-ix}$ form which eventually can be expressed in terms of  $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

It is a very standard description, and can be found in any ODE book.

Comment: Your method works if the roots are real and distinct. A little bit of more effort is required to guarantee that in general $y1,y2$ can be found which are real and LI.